# C++ setup columns using cout

Tags: c++, multiple-columns, cout, setw

So i'm just starting to learn c++ and i'm curious if its a way to formate your output with cout so it will look nicely and structured in columns

for example.

```
string fname = "testname";
    string lname = "123";
    double height = 1.6;

    string fname2 = "short";
    string lname2 = "123";
    double height2 = 1.8;

    cout << "Name" << setw(30) << "Height[m]" << endl;
    cout << fname + " " + lname << right << setw(20) << setprecision(2) << fixed << height << endl;
    cout << fname2 + " " + lname2 << right << setw(20) << setprecision(2) << fixed << height2 << endl
```

The output looks like this:

```
 Name                   Height[m]
 testname 123              1.60
 short 123              1.80
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Name                   Height[m]
testname 123             1.60
short 123                1.80
```

The problem i'm trying to solve is that i want to place height at a specific position from name but depending what length of name i take the value of height either gets far away to the right or will be very close to the left. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, with an output stream like `std::cout`, you **cannot travel back in time** and modify output which was already performed. That makes sense -- just imagine `std::cout` wrote into a file because you launched your program with `program.exe > test.txt`, and `test.txt` was on a USB drive which has been disconnected in the meanwhile...

So you have to get it right immediately.

Basically, there are two ways to do so.

You can **assume that no entry in the first column will ever be wider** than a certain number of characters, which is what you have attempted. The problem is that your `setw` is at the wrong position and that `right` should be `left`. A stream manipulator must be placed *before* the elements which should be affected. And since you want left-aligned columns, you need `left`:

```
cout << left << setw(20) << "Name" << "Height[m]" << endl;
cout << left << setw(20) << fname + " " + lname << setprecision(2) << fixed << height << endl;
cout << left << setw(20) << fname2 + " " + lname2 << setprecision(2) << fixed << height2 << endl;
```

But this solution is not very general. What if you'll have a name with 21 characters? Or with 30 characters? Or 100 characters? What you really want is a solution in which the column is automatically set only as wide as necessary.

The only way to do this is to collect all entries *before* printing them, **finding the longest one**, setting the column width accordingly and only *then* print everything.

Here is one possible implementation of this idea:

```
std::vector<std::string> const first_column_entries
{
    "Name",
    fname + " " + lname,
    fname2 + " " + lname2
};

auto const width_of_longest_entry = std::max_element(std::begin(first_column_entries), std::end(first_column_entries),
    [](std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.size() < rhs.size();
    }
)->size();

// some margin:
auto const column_width = width_of_longest_entry + 3;

std::cout << std::left << std::setw(column_width) << "Name" << "Height[m]" << "\n";
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(column_width) << fname + " " + lname << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << height << "\n";
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(column_width) << fname2 + " " + lname2 << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << height2 << "\n";
```

The next step of evolution would be generalising the `std::vector` into a self-written class called `Table` and iterating that `Table`'s rows in a loop in order to print the entries.

Comment: You should add `"Name"` to `first_column_entries`. `fname + " " + lname` and  `fname2 + " " + lname2` could both result in a single space...

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Good point. I refrained from posting a complete program, but this change makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
string fname = "testname";
string lname = "123";
double height = 1.6;

string fname2 = "short";
string lname2 = "123";
double height2 = 1.8;

cout << left << setw(30) << "Name" << left << "Height[m]" << endl;
cout << left << setw(30) << fname + " " + lname << right << setw(6) << setprecision(2) << fixed << height << endl;
cout << left << setw(30) << fname2 + " " + lname2 << right << setw(6) << setprecision(2) << fixed << height2 << endl;
```